# Using VPN on Docker container running on Synology NAS

Tags: docker, vpn, openvpn, synology

I've tried multiple Docker images all running OpenVPN, and the result is always the same:

```
openvpn: error while loading shared libraries: liblzo2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

Oddly I can get one of the images to periodically run, no ryme or reason I've been able to identify there though.

It's not the first time someone has run into this with Synology, see for example: https://github.com/haugene/docker-transmission-openvpn/discussions/2224. Sadly no real solutions so far though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the option "Execute container using high privilege," the workaround that I found here (https://github.com/haugene/docker-transmission-openvpn/issues/1871#issuecomment-877255193) seems to work for me.

You'll need to uncheck "Execute container using high privilege", start the container, let it fail, check "Execute container using high privilege" and start the container again.

This seems like a bug with Synology's implementation of the "Execute container using high privilege" option.